# smbd.service is failed to start

Tags: 16.04, samba, systemd

Output of `apt install samba`:

`/usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

`journalctl -u smbd.service` output:

[image: journalctl -u smbd.service output]

`/etc/init.d/smbd status` output:

[image: /etc/init.d/smbd status output]

`journalctl -u smbd.service | sed 's/^/> /'` output:

```
Jan 14 14:59:24 ubuntu smbd[1117]:  * Starting SMB/CIFS daemon smbd
Jan 14 14:59:27 ubuntu smbd[1117]: /usr/sbin/smbd: error while loading shared libraries: libwinbind-client.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please don't add texts on images copy and paste it!

Comment: Please add the output from `journalctl -u smbd.service` to your [post](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1109606/edit)

Comment: i tried but getting the same result,

Comment: Starting LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (sm
Jan 14 14:59:24 ubuntu smbd[1117]:  * Starting SMB/CIFS daemon smbd
Jan 14 14:59:27 ubuntu smbd[1117]: /usr/sbin/smbd: error while loading shared li
Jan 14 14:59:27 ubuntu smbd[1117]:    ...fail!
Jan 14 14:59:27 ubuntu systemd[1]: smbd.service: Control process exited, code=ex
Jan 14 14:59:27 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS dae
Jan 14 14:59:27 ubuntu systemd[1]: smbd.service: Unit entered failed state.

Comment: @kiranduba Can you please [add](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1109606/edit) the output to your post, it is unreadable in the comment section .

Comment: @SimonSudler i added screenshot output to my post. Can you please check and give me a soltuion

Comment: @kiranduba Please don't add screenshots, they cannot be search and also there is output missing (ass you can see in your last screenshot). Use a block quote (see [help](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting)). Create the output with `journalctl -u smbd.service | sed 's/^/> /'` and add it to the post.

Comment: @SimonSudler i added as a blockquote please check